# Add Current and Total Slide Counters to Bootstrap 5 Carousel

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

Is there a way to add a number for the current slide and total slides to the following carousel example using Bootstrap 5? The counters are represented in the `carousel-pager` div below, with `pager-current` being the current slide number, and `pager-total` being the total number of slides.

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-pager">
        <div class="pager-current">00</div>
        <div class="pager-total">00</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

sett up :

```
var imgs = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].getElementsByTagName('*'),0);

document.getElementsByClassName('total')[0].innerHTML = imgs.length ;

//create a global variable 
var currentImg = 1;
```

and add this to anything that changes the current img like a button or a timer ...:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('pager-current')[0].innerHTML = (++currentImg) % imgs.length ;
```

Comment: I suggest you use a plugin btw